# How can i make nested loop in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

Hello i try loop in loop for knockout.js bindings but having trouble with it.

My View Model

```
<script>
function Category(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.Products = ko.observableArray
    ([{
        id: ko.observable(data.Products.Id), Name: ko.observable(data.Products.Name),
    }]);
}
function CatListViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Category = ko.observableArray([]);
    Category.Products = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON("/Home/Get", function (allData) {
        var mappedCats = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Category(item); });
        self.Category(mappedCats);
        console.log(allData);
        console.log(mappedCats);
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new CatListViewModel());
```

Html elements

```
<ul data-bind='foreach:Category'>
    <li><span data-bind='text:Name'></span>
        <ul data-bind='foreach:Category.Products'>
            <li data-bind='text:Name'></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Server side Model

```
        public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var catList = new List<Category>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var procList = new List<Product>();
            var Cat = new Category()
            {
                Id = i.ToString(),
                Name = "Category " + i,
            };
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                var prod = new Product()
                {
                    Id = j.ToString(),
                    Name = i + " Cats " + j + " Prod",
                    Price = i + j.ToString(),

                };
                procList.Add(prod);
            }
            Cat.Products = procList;
            catList.Add(Cat);
        }
        return Json(catList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Html output

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:Category">
    <li><span data-bind="text:Name">Category 0</span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach:Category.Products"></ul>
    </li>

    <li><span data-bind="text:Name">Category 1</span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach:Category.Products"></ul>
    </li>

    <li><span data-bind="text:Name">Category 2</span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach:Category.Products"></ul>
    </li>   

   ... More item
</ul>
```

The outside loop renders correctly, but I get nothing from the inside loop, not even an error message.

Comment: I suspect Category.Products does not contain what you expect. Check the raw data by putting `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(Category.Products, null, 2)"></pre>` above the second foreach in your html. Maybe you just need to replace "Category.Products" by "$data.Products".

Comment: Thank you,I think you are right i put your binding above second foreach and output is [] but i dont have any idea about fixing this problem would you help about this problem?

Comment: Does the "Category" object contain what you expect (do a similar check as before but before the first foreach)? Is it an array of Categories that each contain an array of Products? Then you just have to replace "Category.Products" with "$data.Products" in the second foreach, because you probably want the products for each category and the "$data" token will refer to the current iterated item of the outer foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML doesn't look right to me, remove the `Category.` in the `Products` block as it will reference each parent `Category`by default:

```
<!-- Loop over each Category -->
<ul data-bind="foreach:Category">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
        <!-- Loop over each Product in the current category -->
        <ul data-bind="foreach:Products">                
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If that doesn't work, use `$data` to specifically reference the parent `Category` properties: `foreach:$data.Products`.

Comment: Thanks i try it too but still can't make it i think my View Model is wrong but i cant solve that problem.

Comment: @ierhalim if you create a JSFiddle that replicates the issue I will take a look